# How to create own dataset for FCN with caffe?

Tags: dataset, caffe, lmdb

How to convert image to lmdb for fcn with caffe? You know, It's easy create own dataset for image classification with caffe, but how to create own dataset for semantic segment for fcn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code. Make the necessary path changes. Please read the code carefully before using it.

```
import caffe
import lmdb
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import glob
from random import shuffle

# Initialize the Image set:

NumberTrain = 1111 # Number of Training Images

NumberTest = 1112 # Number of Testing Images

Rheight = 380 # Required Height

Rwidth = 500 # Required Width

LabelHeight = 380 # Downscaled height of the label

LabelWidth = 500 # Downscaled width of the label


# Read the files in the Data Folder

inputs_data_train = sorted(glob.glob("/home/<user>/caffe-with_crop/examples/fcn-32s/TrainData/*.jpg"))
inputs_data_valid = sorted(glob.glob("/home/<user>/caffe-with_crop/examples/fcn-32s/ValData/*.jpg"))
inputs_label = sorted(glob.glob("/home/<user>/caffe-with_crop/examples/fcn-32s/VOC2011/SegmentationClass/*.png"))

shuffle(inputs_data_train) # Shuffle the DataSet
shuffle(inputs_data_valid) # Shuffle the DataSet

inputs_Train = inputs_data_train[:NumberTrain] # Extract the training data from the complete set

inputs_Test = inputs_data_valid[:NumberTest] # Extract the testing data from the complete set

# Creating LMDB for Training Data

print("Creating Training Data LMDB File ..... ")

in_db = lmdb.open('/home/<user>/caffe-with_crop/examples/fcn-32s/TrainVOC_Data_lmdb',map_size=int(1e14))

with in_db.begin(write=True) as in_txn:

    for in_idx, in_ in enumerate(inputs_Train):
        print in_idx
        im = np.array(Image.open(in_)) # or load whatever ndarray you need
        Dtype = im.dtype
        im = im[:,:,::-1]
        im = Image.fromarray(im)
        im = im.resize([Rheight, Rwidth], Image.ANTIALIAS)
        im = np.array(im,Dtype)     

        im = im.transpose((2,0,1))
        im_dat = caffe.io.array_to_datum(im)
        in_txn.put('{:0>10d}'.format(in_idx),im_dat.SerializeToString())

in_db.close()

# Creating LMDB for Training Labels

print("Creating Training Label LMDB File ..... ")

in_db = lmdb.open('/home/<user>/caffe-with_crop/examples/fcn-32s/TrainVOC_Label_lmdb',map_size=int(1e14))

with in_db.begin(write=True) as in_txn:

    for in_idx, in_ in enumerate(inputs_Train):
        print in_idx
        in_label = in_[:-25]+'VOC2011/SegmentationClass/'+in_[-15:-3]+'png' # Change the numbers as per requirement
        L = np.array(Image.open(in_)) # or load whatever ndarray you need
        Dtype = L.dtype
        L = L[:,:,::-1]
        Limg = Image.fromarray(L)
        Limg = Limg.resize([LabelHeight, LabelWidth],Image.NEAREST) # To resize the Label file to the required size 

        L = np.array(Limg,Dtype)

        L = L.reshape(L.shape[0],L.shape[1],1)

        L = L.transpose((2,0,1))

        L_dat = caffe.io.array_to_datum(L)
        in_txn.put('{:0>10d}'.format(in_idx),L_dat.SerializeToString())

in_db.close()

# Creating LMDB for Testing Data

print("Creating Testing Data LMDB File ..... ")

in_db = lmdb.open('/home/<user>/caffe-with_crop/examples/fcn-32s/TestVOC_Data_lmdb',map_size=int(1e14))

with in_db.begin(write=True) as in_txn:

    for in_idx, in_ in enumerate(inputs_Test):
        print in_idx    
        im = np.array(Image.open(in_)) # or load whatever ndarray you need
        Dtype = im.dtype
        im = im[:,:,::-1]
        im = Image.fromarray(im)
        im = im.resize([Rheight, Rwidth], Image.ANTIALIAS)
        im = np.array(im,Dtype)     

        im = im.transpose((2,0,1))
        im_dat = caffe.io.array_to_datum(im)
        in_txn.put('{:0>10d}'.format(in_idx),im_dat.SerializeToString())

in_db.close()

# Creating LMDB for Testing Labels

print("Creating Testing Label LMDB File ..... ")

in_db = lmdb.open('/home/<user>/caffe-with_crop/examples/fcn-32s/TestVOC_Label_lmdb',map_size=int(1e14))

with in_db.begin(write=True) as in_txn:

    for in_idx, in_ in enumerate(inputs_Test):
        print in_idx    
        in_label = in_[:-25]+'VOC2011/SegmentationClass/'+in_[-15:-3]+'png' # Change the numbers as per requirement
        L = np.array(Image.open(in_)) # or load whatever ndarray you need
        Dtype = L.dtype
        L = L[:,:,::-1]
        Limg = Image.fromarray(L)
        Limg = Limg.resize([LabelHeight, LabelWidth],Image.NEAREST) # To resize the Label file to the required size 

        L = np.array(Limg,Dtype)

        L = L.reshape(L.shape[0],L.shape[1],1)

        L = L.transpose((2,0,1))

        L_dat = caffe.io.array_to_datum(L)
        in_txn.put('{:0>10d}'.format(in_idx),L_dat.SerializeToString())

in_db.close()
```

Comment: Hi, man, how do I fix this problem, I known the label image should be single channel, but it report this error.  traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/eclipse-workspace/trainDataset/train.py", line 79, in <module>
    L = L.reshape(L.shape[0],L.shape[1],1)
ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged @Harsh Wardhan

Comment: Did you check your image dimensions and those given in the script?

Comment: I have checked it, all of my image dimensions is 512*512, but I have solved this problem simply with NIVIDIA DIGITS, thanks